# Nvidia Drivers Install problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have some trouble with my Nvidia drivers to install.
When I choose the right/latest driver and install it after a reboot it crashes and says Nvidia-detection crash.
The same is although when I download the latest nvidia driver form the website and install it. So I have big trouble wo get it run. I only didn't get errors/crashes when I use the open source drivers.
I would be happy to get some help with this issue.
I'm having a GeForce RTX 2070 max Q.
I'm Using Ubuntu Budgie 20.4.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: It is already disabled.

Comment: I assume you meant "Budgie" in of "Ubuntu20.4 bugdie"? Please revert the change if not.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is related, but i enabled a settings "Only enable on windows operating systems" on the GPU in BIOS.
If I disabled that setting in BIOS ubuntu 20.02 crashes right after startup.

Comment: How can this be helpful for using Ubuntu?

Comment: I know is sound strange but it worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It is not "strange". You disabled the Nvidia GPU and all kinda "worked".

Comment: Please read my comment. I ENABLED the setting

Comment: So you enabled the setting to use the GPU only on Windows. 1) I've never seen such a setting, only specific MBs have it; 2) It disables Nvidia GPU on non-Windows OS's.

Comment: YES....(This would have been much faster if you just read my comments)
1) Mine have some settings.
2) No it just disables some settings on the GPU